# Next.js 13 - Accessing search params from a deeply nested server component in the same route segment?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-server-components, urlsearchparams

I know that search params are accessible in page component props, but can the deeply-nested, non-page server components inside the same route segment also access search params somehow? For example, let's assume a scenario. We have the following component structure:

```
RouteSegmentPage
  ServerComponentLevel1
    ...
    ServerComponentLevelN
      LeafClientComponent
AnotherRouteSegmentPage
  ...
```

`RouteSegmentPage` displays a rich page that consists of many nested non-page child components, all in the same route segment. `ServerComponentLevelN` needs to fetch some data using search params. How can we achieve this without prop drilling search params from `RouteSegmentPage` to all the way down to `ServerComponentLevelN`?

Note: `ServerComponentLevelN` needs to stay as server component.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround for this here
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51818
by  [icyJoseph](https://github.com/icyJoseph)

The work around is to basically avoid using hooks , and stick to only js .

1. create store

```js
// app/store.tsx
const createStore = () => {
  let data: string | null = null;

  const setData = (next: string) => {
    data = next;
  };

  const getData = () => {
    return data;
  };

  return { setData, getData };
};

export const store = createStore();
```

2. Save search params into the store .

```js
// app/[foo]/[bar]/page.tsx

import { Outer } from "../../Outer";
import { store } from "../../store";

export default function Page({
  params,
}: {
  params: { foo: string; bar: string };
}) {
  const { foo, bar } = params;
  store.setData(`/${foo}/${bar}`);
  return <Outer />;
}
```

3. Access your searchParms saved in store

```js
import { store } from "./store";

export const Inner = () => {
  return <div>{store.getData()}</div>;
};
```

Comment: Heads up: the shared store module isn't isolated between requests, so one user's data could end up being read by a different user. Here's a workaround: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/51818#discussioncomment-7303399